# Value error when fitting Prophet() model - parameter not recognized

Tags: python, valueerror, model-fitting, facebook-prophet

so I get this message right below the input cell when trying to fit the model:

**INFO:numexpr.utils:NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
INFO:fbprophet:Disabling daily seasonality. Run prophet with daily_seasonality=True to override this.**

After setting daily_seasonality=True and running the cell again, Value error shows up that **parameter daily_seasonality is not recognized.**

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem.Access Anaconda Prompt for the environment that you are working with as admin. But it works after I follow some steps:

1- `conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet`

2- `conda remove --force fbprophet`

3- In your jupyter notebook use pip : `install fbprophet`

Comment: Hey, thanks. In number 1, is that actually installing a new channel and then a package ?

Comment: yes exactly,then i remove the package and reinstalled it because when i train my model my jupyter notebook crashed always. finally it works with these steps